# In NodeJS/Sequelize/MySQL, how do I insert time as per local time zone on the server?

Tags: mysql, node.js

We are trying to insert datetime values with the following query -
insert into products (name,createdon) values ('product1', now())
We are firing a raw query using sequelize.
The value is being stored in UTC format.

Firing the same query directly from MySQL, stores the value in local time.

We need the value stored in local time and not in UTC. How do we achieve that here?

Answer (score 4):

I also faced same issue. At the time of connection with sequlize and Mysql you can pass `timezone`. So it will always using this `timezone` for saving data. Here is what i found:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', { 
    timezone: '+05:30', //here you can pass timezone
    host: 'host',
    logging: true,
});
```

But this is not a good solution because if you use your application from 2 different timezone then it will use same timezone for both, so data will be incorrect.

---

Good solution is always use UTC `timezone:'00:00'` for saving data and while fetching result show in user's appropriate timezone format. It means if user accessing website from `US` manipulate DateTime in `US's` format and show, and if your accessing data from `India` then manipulate DateTime in `India's` format and show. For this you need to do some DateTime manipulation. For this manipulation you can use [**Moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/).